# Simulating first in first out on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, fifo

I simulated a first in first out job scheduling using javascript like this, I thought it was perfect at first but realized that it won't work under certain conditions..

```
Array.prototype.fifo = function(frames) {
  var results = [], result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result = result.slice(0);
    var inObjects = result.inObjects('page', this[i]);
    if(result.length == frames && !inObjects) {
      result[i%frames] = page: this[i];
    } else if (!inObjects) {
      result.push(page: this[i]);
    }
    results.push(result);
  };
  return {result: results};
};
```

Now if you can see that modulo, i think that one is causing the problem.

```
// eg
   [1,2,3,4,5,6].fifo(3);
// returns
   [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [4,2,3], [4,5,3], [4,5,6]
```

While this is correct, sorting will fail if the number `i` equals `frames` and when `modulo'ed`, the remainder will be zero thus won't work.

```
// e.g.
// [1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6].fifo(3)
// returns
// [1], [1], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [5,2,4], [5,6,4]
```

My best bet is to save a property of `age` to each page and push them as an object to keep track who's gonna be replaced. What do you think? Is there a simpler way to do this.

**Edit**
For that `Array.prototype.inObject`, I am checking if a current value is in the array of objects.

```
Array.prototype.inObjects = function(key, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if(this[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && this[i][key] == value){
      return true;
    }
  };
  return false;
};
```

Comment: What is `Array.prototype.inObjects` ?

Comment: I am confused. Don't javascript arrays already have the ability to simulate a FIFO using `push` and `shift`?

Comment: shift and pop only removes the first element or the last element...push only push contents as a last element, not pushing to where the oldest element is.